# Excel VBA - Do Until Blank Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm recording a macro and need some help. I'd like copy and paste the values from the column G of the "SalesData" worksheet into cells A2, A12, A22 etc of the "Results" worksheet until there's no more values in the column G.

VBA is pretty new to me, I've tried using Do/Until, but everything crashed. Could you please help me? Please see the code I've recorded below. Thank you!

```
Sub(x)

 Sheets("SalesData").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Results").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("A12").Select
    Sheets("SalesData").Select
    Range("G3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Results").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("A22").Select
        Sheets("SalesData").Select
    Range("G4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Results").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        Range("A32").Select
        Sheets("SalesData").Select
    Range("G5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Results").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: So data in G2 goes to A12 and data in G3 goes 10 rows below to A22, and so on ... ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Stop what you are doing and watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5&t=3128s).  You should watch the entire series but that video is a must see.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! I'm going to watch it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to find the last cell in the column first then use a `For` loop.

Since you are only doing the values we can avoid the clipboard and assign the values directly.

Since you paste is every 10 cells we can use a separate counter to move down 10 each loop.

```
Sub x()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lst As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
'use variable to limit the number of times we type the same thing
Set ws = Worksheets("Results")
'First row of the output
j = 2
'using with and the "." in front of those items that belong to it also limits the typing.
With Worksheets("SalesData")
    'Find the last row with values in Column G
    lst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop from the second row to the last row.
    For i = 2 To lst
        'Assign the value
        ws.Cells(j, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        'Move down 10 rows on the output
        j = j + 10
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: beat me too it since I took time to clarify exactly what user wanted :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I just go with my first impression and delete if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Remember, you never get a second chance to make a first impression! :) ...  *(except when you do)*

Comment: Great Scotts!  :D

Answer (score 2):

here is the same thing but using range variables

```
Sub x()

    Dim src As Range
    Dim dst As Range

    Set dst = Worksheets("Results").Range("a2")   ' point to top cell of destination

    With Worksheets("SalesData")

        For Each src In Range(.Cells(2, "g"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "g").End(xlUp)) ' loop through used cell range in column G
            dst.Value = src.Value
            Set dst = dst.Offset(10)               ' move destination pointer down 10 rows
        Next src

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just for fun/practice for another way to do it:

```
Sub copyFromG()
Dim copyRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim salesWS As Worksheet, resultsWS As Worksheet

Set salesWS = Sheets("SalesData")
Set resultsWS = Sheets("Results")

Set copyRng = salesWS.Range("G2:G" & salesWS.Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row) ' assuming you have a header in G1

For Each cel In copyRng
    resultsWS.Range("A" & 2 + 10 * copyRng.Rows(cel.Row).Row - 30).Value = cel.Value
Next cel

End Sub
```