# Building a Do Until loop to loop a column until empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble building a do until loop that will loop the column D starting at D4 and keep repeating the Select Case function until it comes across an empty cell. Attached is my code. I apologize if this is a redundant question, I've tried everything I've found and it's not working so I'm wondering if something else in code is messing it up.

```
Sub FindSupervisior()
    Dim Position As String

    range("D4").Select
    Position = ActiveCell

     'i need to add a loop around this section to do the entire column until empty
      Select Case Position
            Case "Woodyard / Pulp E&I"
                Position = "Boss A"
            Case "Maintenance - Primary Pro"
                Position = "Boss B"
      End Select
      ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Position
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: You should watch these videos [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
, [Excel VBA Introduction Part 15 - Do Until and Do While Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGauctajWPQ&index=16&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 3):

You will find the answer by Scott Craner useful here [Excel VBA - Do Until Blank Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352964/excel-vba-do-until-blank-cell)

Alternatively here's a simple example

```
 Dim i = 4 ' starting row
 While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) ' column 4 = column D etc

     Select Case etc .......
     Cells(i,5).Value = Position

     i = i + 1
 Wend
```

Comment: a quick n' tidy third answer... you're off to a good start, Welcome!+

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code:

```
t=4

LastRow = Activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count,4).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until t=LastRow

Position = Activesheet.Cells(t,4).Value
‘Your code 

t=t+4

Loop
```